# Disable Fastboot/Hyperboot Windows 10 Creator Update

Tags: dual-boot, windows

Does anyone know how to disable the fastboot in the Windows 10 Creator update from over-riding the boot order "Grub" each time Windows boots? I have to press F-10 each time Windows boots and change the boot order.

Answer (score 1):

To disable Fastboot for Windows 10 Creator Update, follow these steps:

1. Search "Power Plan" in Windows start menu, open "Edit power plan".
2. Go one level above to "Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options"
3. To the left, click "Choose what the power buttons do."
4. Click "Change settings that a currently unavailable."
5. Uncheck "Turn on fast startup (recommanded) " on the same page blow, Save Changes.
6. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Although this does not disable Fastboot, (Not Possible AFAIK) It does allow Grub UEFI to load and not be overwritten each time by Windows 10 "Creator".
Just Move Ubuntu, (Grub UEFI Boot Loader) to the Top of the Menu and disable Windows Boot Loader.
**

### Easy UEFI (Windows Based Program)

[Easy UEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html)

Also a very nice tool for this operation...
[Daniel Richter's Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer)