# Windows 10 scanning and repairing drive (E:) which contains my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: uefi, 18.04, drive

Every time I start Windows 10 dual boot with Ubuntu 18.04 (UEFI) I got error message that

> Scanning and repairing drive (E:)

[image: repair]

[image]

Contents of `/etc/fstab`(moved from comments to question):

```
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass> 
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation 
UUID=2bb771db-9d37-4b94-88b5-4bcbac3304b6 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1 
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation 
UUID=6A1D-DD43 /boot/efi vfat umask=0077 0 1 
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation 
UUID=43832aa0-8926-431b-8195-f14695b259bb none swap sw 0 0
```

Comment: Can you list the contents of your `/etc/fstab` file?

Comment: # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=2bb771db-9d37-4b94-88b5-4bcbac3304b6 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=6A1D-DD43  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=43832aa0-8926-431b-8195-f14695b259bb none            swap    sw              0       0

Comment: Looking at your `/etc/fstab` (which I moved from your comment to your question) you are not mounting Windows partitions within Ubuntu. So it would not appear that Ubuntu is messing up Windows. Make sure when Windows **Fast Boot** is not enabled. See: https://askubuntu.com/a/931198/307523 to turn off fastboot. Also most people turn off Windows Hibernation.

Comment: I had already disabled fast startup

Comment: windows 10 repairs my ubuntu drive partition(E:) not ubuntu.

Comment: Can you make your terminal screen a little wider and run `lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT,SIZE,UUID` then copy and paste the output into your question?

Comment: done check here https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvbWx.png

Comment: I opened my disk in Gparted and all the partitions were flagged as 'msftdata' microsoft filesystems. Presumably leftover from their creation, and despite being reformatted during the install. Removing these flags from the Mint partitions has solved the problem unchecking it solved my problem

Comment: If you like, you can write a formal answer and accept it by clicking the grey check mark that appears next to the answer after you post it.

Answer (score 0):

Windows won't give a drive letter to a partition with a filesystem type it can't read, so since it's working on drive `E:`, it's not doing anything to your Ubuntu partitions.

It's doing something to one of your other NTFS partitions. You have five NTFS partitions total.